# Pass current step output to next step and write to flatfile

Tags: spring-batch

I need to prepare two set of List and write them into FlatFile. The first set will be only simple retrieving from SQL and before write into FlatFile will do some string formatting. Another set of data slightly complex, first I need to get data from some table and insert into a temp table. The data will grab from this temp table and similarly need to perform some string formatting and also updating the temp file. Finally, both set data write into FlatFile.

Come into Spring Batch, I will have 3 steps.

```
First Step
   First Reader read from DB
   First Processor string formatting
   First Writer write into file

Second Step
   BeforeRead Retrieve and Insert to Temp table
   Second Reader read from temp table 
   Second Processor string formatting and update temp table status
   Second Writer write into file

Third Step
  MUltiResourceItemReader read two files
  Write into Final File

Tasklet
  Delete both file and purge the temp table.
```

My question now is for first and second step if I don't write into file, possible to pass the data into third step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking in account what Hansjoerg Wingeier said, below are custom implementations of ListItemWriter and ListItemReader which lets you define a `name` property. This property is used as a key to store the list in the `JobExecutionContext`.

The reader :

```
public class CustomListItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T>, StepExecutionListener {

    private String name;
    private List<T> list;

    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
            return list.remove(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        list = (List<T>) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The writer :

```
public class CustomListItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T>, StepExecutionListener {

    private String name;
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        for (T item : items) {
            list.add(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {}

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put(name, list);
        return null;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you don't want to do that.

If you just have a couple of hundred entries, it would work. You could, for instance, write a special class, that implements the reader and writer interface. When writing, just store the data in a list, when reading, read the entries from the list. Just instantiate it as a bean and use it in both steps (1 and 2) as your writer. by simply make the write method synchronized, it would even work when step 1 and 2 are executed in parallel.

But the problem is, that this solution doesn't scale with the amount of your input data. the more data you read, the more memory you need.

This is one of the key concepts of batch-processing: having a constant memory usage regardless of the amount of data that has to be processed.